# Delphi - кодировка

Tags: delphi, кодировка

Я хочу кодировать текст в база69.

```
RichEdit1.Text:=idencodermime1.Encode(RichEdit1.Text) ;
  RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile(Edit1.Text);
```

Но дело в том, что шифрует только английский,а не русский как раньше.
Вместо русского в файле появляется какая-то не понятная фигня.

Comment: база69 ? что еще за извращения ?

Comment: BASE64! Блин, ну неужели так трудно аккуратно писать и разобраться хотя бы в наименованиях?

Comment: А что за непонятная фигня там появляется? Должны получаться как обычно латинские буквы и цифры.. Если какой-то стандартный метод не работает, ну так реализуйте его сами.. BASE64 - простое кодирование.

Answer (score 1):

Если версия delphi 2009 и выше то нужно задавать кодировку например

```
  Memo2.Text:=IdEncoderMIME1.Encode(Memo1.Text, TEncoding.Unicode )
```

А при декоде в инди наверно забыли про кодировки но вот так работает

```
  LStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
      IdDecoderMIME1.DecodeBegin(LStream);
      try
        IdDecoderMIME1.Decode(Memo2.Text);
      finally
        IdDecoderMIME1.DecodeEnd;
      end;
      LStream.Position := 0;
      Memo1.Text := IdGlobal.ReadStringFromStream(LStream, -1, TEncoding.Unicode);
 LStream.Free;
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласен. Стандартный библиотечный класс с методами Encode и Decode должен работать.
Если что-то не так в интернете множество примеров.
К слову о base69 это возможно, просто сдвиг на 5 позиций больше делать =)